# How to convert an object composed by two arrays of objects into an array of one property of each object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

this is the initial input
Object {
​
Belleza: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { category: "Belleza", text: "Alimentacion Saludable" }
​​
1: Object { category: "Belleza", text: "Rutinas" }
​​
2: Object { category: "Belleza", text: "Cuidado Facial" }
​​
​​
​
Viajes: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { category: "Viajes", text: "Trabajo remoto" }
​​
1: Object { category: "Viajes", text: "Viajar con poco dinero" }

​​}

I have the object above and I need  to convert it into somthing like this:

{

Belleza:["Alimentacion Saludable","Rutinas","Cuidado Facial"],
Viajes:[Trabajo remoto,Viajar con poco dinero]

}

I tried whit reducing method but didn't work, to be hones I dont know how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce to build object and collect text value from array of objects.

```
const input = {Belleza: [{ category: "Belleza", text: "Alimentacion Saludable" },  { category: "Belleza", text: "Rutinas" }, { category: "Belleza", text: "Cuidado Facial" }], Viajes: [{ category: "Viajes", text: "Trabajo remoto" }, { category: "Viajes", text: "Viajar con poco dinero" }]};
const output = Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, key) => {
  const value = input[key];
  acc[key] = value.map(item => item.text);

  return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the entries of the object, using `Array#map` to extract all the text properties.

```js
const o = {Belleza: [{ category: "Belleza", text: "Alimentacion Saludable" },  { category: "Belleza", text: "Rutinas" }, { category: "Belleza", text: "Cuidado Facial" }], Viajes: [{ category: "Viajes", text: "Trabajo remoto" }, { category: "Viajes", text: "Viajar con poco dinero" }]};
const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k, v.map(x => x.text)]));
console.log(res);
```